# ccavenue is not showing in magento 2.2 frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have Downloaded and Installed cc avenue in my `magento 2.2` website its working fine in back-end, but when i go to my checkout page from front-end
my extension is not showing there. If anyone know please Help.

Comment: Are you using default magento2 checkout?

Comment: yes i'm using default magento2 checkout